# Как сделать поиск по txt файлу с выводом найденой строки полностью?

Tags: php

В текстовом файле записан список студентов в виде строчек.В каждой строке через пробел написаны логин,группа,фамилия , имя ,отчество.
Создать скрипт с WEB-формой для поиска студента по варианту :
1- по логину
2- по фамилии
3-по фамилии и имени
4-по фамилии и отчеству

Comment: Читаете файл построчно (или весь в массив, но потом построчно все равно по этому массиву идете), разбиваете строку на поля (с смой строкой ничего при этом не произойдет, она целиком в переменной) (explode видимо) проверяете содержимое требуемых полей на требуемый текст, если совпало - печатаете строку из переменной

Comment: лучше взять mysql и спарсить этот файл туда, а после уже искать по колонкам.

Comment: Комментарии сделали мой вечер! Да, PHP -- особый ЯП.

Comment: За решением лабы, надо идти к местным нёрдам и проставляться ;).  Хоть бы какой код написали ...